# UIScrollView Not Scrolling In iOS 7 StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a UILabel along with a UIWebView together in a view controller and want them to scroll together. So to accomplish that, i have added a UIScrollView behind these two views but the UIScrollView is just not scrolling. I am using Storyboard and iOS 7 SDK.

[image: UIScrollView]

I have seen many questions but they are not of much help. Some are suggesting that i should disable the AutoLayout that i cannot do due to the requirements of my project. What else can i do to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: What is the contentSize of the scrollView? And how are you exactly scrolling? The webView has a scroll of it's own, so you're basically nesting scrollViews which will probably work different than you intended.

Comment: @Adis i have set the contentSize of scrollView to different values but it didn't work. UIWebView is scrolling but the UIScrollView is not.

Comment: Are you touching inside the webView, or outside? If inside, the webView is probably stealing the touch events. Also, the content size of the scroll needs to be bigger than it's frame to scroll.

Comment: if i touch inside the UIWebView then of course UIWebView is scrolling but if i touch outside, then UIScrollView is not scrolling. I have tried disabling the touch of UIWebView which makes the UIWebView stop scrolling but UIScrollView still not scrolling.

Comment: if you have 2 scrollviews nested in each other, only one can respond to the touch, you will have to disable scrolling on the webview or the scrollview.

Comment: @Kronusdark i have already disabled the touch on the UIWebView but that doesn't activate the touch of UIScrollView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation, you shouldn't use UIWebView inside UIScrollView. What you can do is to add your UILabels and UIWebView inside aother UIView and then add this UIview inside the UIScrollView.

Secondly, you have to set the contentSize of the UIScrollView in order for it to work.

You also have to disable the scrolling of UIWebView that is embeded inside the UIScrollView.

Still if your problem is not solved. It is better to just turn of AutoLayout. I have had the same issue and i wasnt able to solve it without disable the AutoLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for UIWebView states:

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

You need to wrap the label and web view in a regular UIView. Add the regular view to the scroll view.